# How to prevent html injection(inserting) to avoid ad

Tags: google-chrome, browser, html-injections

I have facing the problem on avoid the ads in my browsers. I searched many tools and included extensions in browser. Also i re-installed the browsers but i cant able to stop populating ads in browsers.

Is there any way to stop this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Chrome with addons like AdBlock and are still receiving adverts, you probably have adware. This can either be a proper virus or just a malicious extension installed in Chrome.

If using Chrome: Search your extensions for any you didn't install and remove them.

Do a full virus scan, then install AdBlock.

Also, I doubt this is the right board for this question, but there's the answer anyway.

Comment: If the answer was correct, don't forget to upvote/put as the correct answer.